# How can we "assign" LiveData from Room to MutableLiveData, within ViewModel

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

Recently, I am stuck with the following code.

```
public class NoteViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private final MutableLiveData<List<Note>> notesLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public NoteViewModel() {
        LiveData<List<Note>> notesLiveDataFromRepository = NoteRepository.INSTANCE.getNotes();

        // How can I "assign" LiveData from Room, to MutableLiveData?
    }

}
```

I was wondering, how can I "assign" `LiveData` from `Room`, to `MutableLiveData`?

Using `Transformation.map` and `Transformation.switchMap` wouldn't work, as both returns `LiveData`, not `MutableLiveData`.

---

### Possible workaround

One of the possible solution is that, instead of

```
@Dao
public abstract class NoteDao {
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM plain_note")
    public abstract LiveData<List<Note>> getNotes();
```

I will use

```
@Dao
public abstract class NoteDao {
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM plain_note")
    public abstract List<Note> getNotes();
```

Then, in my `ViewModel`, I will write

```
public class NoteViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private final MutableLiveData<List<Note>> notesLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public NoteViewModel() {
        new Thread(() -> {
            List<Note> notesLiveDataFromRepository = NoteRepository.INSTANCE.getNotes();
            notesLiveData.postValue(notesLiveDataFromRepository);
        }).start();
    }

}
```

I don't really like this approach, as I'm forced to handle threading thingy explicitly.

Is there a better way, to avoid handling threading explicitly?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The trick is to not do any of the actual fetching in the view model.

Getting data, be it from network or database, should be done in the repository. The ViewModel should be agnostic in this regard.

In the ViewModel, use the LiveData class, not MutableLiveData. Unless you really find a use case for it.

```
// In your constructor, no extra thread
notesLiveData = notesLiveDataFromRepository.getAllNotes();
```

Then in your repository you can have the logic in the getAllNotes() method for determining where those notes are coming from. In the repository you have the MutableLiveData. You can then postValue to that, from a thread that is getting the data. That isn't necessary for room though, that is handled for you.

So in your repository you would have another LiveData being returned that is backed directly from a DAO method.

In that case, you need to stick with `public abstract LiveData<List<Note>> getNotes();`.

## Activity

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MyViewModel viewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set up your view model
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);

        // Observe the view model
        viewModel.getMyLiveData().observe(this, s -> {
            // You work with the data provided through the view model here.
            // You should only really be delivering UI updates at this point. Updating
            // a RecyclerView for example.
            Log.v("LIVEDATA", "The livedata changed: "+s);
        });

        // This will start the off-the-UI-thread work that we want to perform.
        MyRepository.getInstance().doSomeStuff();
    }
}
```

## ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    @NonNull
    private MyRepository repo = MyRepository.getInstance();

    @NonNull
    private LiveData<String> myLiveData;

    public MyViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        // The local live data needs to reference the repository live data
        myLiveData = repo.getMyLiveData();
    }

    @NonNull
    public LiveData<String> getMyLiveData() {
        return myLiveData;
    }
}
```

## Repository

```
public class MyRepository {

    private static MyRepository instance;

    // Note the use of MutableLiveData, this allows changes to be made
    @NonNull
    private MutableLiveData<String> myLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public static MyRepository getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            synchronized (MyRepository.class) {
                if(instance == null) {
                    instance = new MyRepository();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    // The getter upcasts to LiveData, this ensures that only the repository can cause a change
    @NonNull
    public LiveData<String> getMyLiveData() {
        return myLiveData;
    }

    // This method runs some work for 3 seconds. It then posts a status update to the live data.
    // This would effectively be the "doInBackground" method from AsyncTask.
    public void doSomeStuff() {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
            }

            myLiveData.postValue("Updated time: "+System.currentTimeMillis());
        }).start();
    }

}
```

Comment: I wish I could see a concrete example in the nice and clear answer.

Comment: @Knossos - Thank you for the explanation, but I'm having trouble conceptualising what you just described. Can you please share some pseudocode snippets so I can understand better?

Comment: I made an example for another answer, I will paste it into this answer too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but can you please explain that in the **Repository** of your example how are you going to cast Rooms liveData to myLiveData?

Comment: There need not be anything complicated about that. I would post what I do, but that rapidly leads down a rabbit hole of database examples. Essentially, I have a LiveData that I [switchMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations#switchmap) on, that lets me know that the database is created and ready. I apply that to the Repository LiveData. That then automatically provides the correct data to the Repository, and everything else, once it is ready to do so.

Comment: @Knossos I like being able to access the Repository using getInstance() in the Activity.  But I already have my Repository constructor referencing my SQLite database with: "public Repository(Application application) {
        RoomDatabase db = RoomDatabase.getDatabase(application);
        Dao = db.Dao();
    }"  How would I keep both, my reference to the database and your Repository singleton for use with the Activity?

Comment: @Knossos in your example DAO methods would be `MutableLiveData` or `LiveData`? Or maybe one of each?

Comment: @Stachu In the DAO, you are only getting data from the database. You would use a `LiveData`.

Answer (score 7):

Very simple.

```
class MainViewModel: ViewModel() {

    @Inject lateinit var currencyRepository: CurrencyRepository

    val notifyCurrencyList = MediatorLiveData<List<Currency?>>()

    init {
        CurrencyApplication.component.inject(this)
    }

    fun loadCurrencyList() {
        notifyCurrencyList.addSource(currencyRepository.loadLatestRates()) {
            notifyCurrencyList.value = it
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Simple and elegant solution. Could have added a brief description about MediatorLiveData. However answer by @Knossos is the recomended way of doing it. We should create a repostitory class which can pull data from either network or database.