# Livedata observer onChanged() is only triggered once?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata

I am following the LiveData samples online, somehow the LiveData is only triggered once, when the activity is created. If I open another activity to update the Oppo Object, then back to the Activity, the onChanged() is not called. I am not sure what goes wrong. Since when I check the LiveData has active observers in onResume(), it returns true though.

Here are the code:

Activity

```
oppoViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(OppViewModel.class);
    OppoViewModel.setOppo(extras.getString(RECORD_ID));
    oppoViewModel
            .getOpportunity()
            .observe(this, oppo -> {
                // Update the UI
            }
    );
```

ViewModel

```
class OppoViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

private var oppo: MutableLiveData<Oppo> = MutableLiveData()
private var compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

fun setOppo(recordId: String) {

    compositeDisposable.add(Single.just(RepositoryProvider.oppoRepository()
            .getOppoByRecordId(recordId))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(object : DisposableSingleObserver<Oppo>() {
                override fun onSuccess(t: Oppo) {
                    oppo.postValue(t)
                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                }
            }))
}

fun getOpportunity(): MutableLiveData<Opp> {
    return oppo
}

override fun onCleared() {
    Timber.e("ViewModel onCleared()")
    compositeDisposable.clear()
    super.onCleared()
}
}
```

I am using RxJava for getting the DB record from SQLite databse, and using  ContentResolver in this case. Originally I thought oppo.postValue should be changed to oppo.setValue, but it still not triggered

Comment: here is one link i found out which is similar to my approach: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49602606/how-can-we-assign-livedata-from-room-to-mutablelivedata-within-viewmodel)

Answer (score 0):

But you have a single subscription for changes

```
Single.just(RepositoryProvider.oppoRepository())
```

In your case, this is not a responsibility of `LiveDate` to consume updated value, you need to be sure that your rx stream will emit new value after it will be updated.

The new value will be set, only if `oppo.postValue(t)` will be triggered while your first activity in the background.

Comment: thank you for the reply @Igor Bykov, but I think Rx stream is not the only cause. Anyway I will keep this post updated when I found out other causes and solutions.